# Shared with .. is disable

Tags: 2016

I'm the site admin, and I'm getting this error and I don't know to get around it or it there a setting that needs switching on.

[image]

Comment: Check if this list has unique permission

Comment: Hey, @HighamLane did you find issue. I am facing same issue

Comment: @BharatKhunti sorry nope

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot seems to be the "listitem" ribbon tab. The menu items "Shared With", "Display Item", "Edit Item", "Delete Item", "Attach file" and "Workflows" are only available after you have selected a specific item in the list view.
Please select an item and the whiched menu item will be available.

If you want to see the permission for the list instead of the list item switch to the "list" ribbon tab and select the menu item "Shared With". It should be on the right side.
[image]

If you want to change permissions for lists or libraries you can also follow this steps:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782